# why c# and java unicode different

Tags: java, unicode

> **Str = test**

```
 The results are not the same I do not know why.
```

### Java code

```
   int[] inData = getInt(Str.getBytes("**unicode**"));
   for (int i = 0; i < inData.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("====EncryStrHex==inData[i]==" + inData[i]);
   }
```

#### result

```
    *========*******Encryints====-2
    ========*******Encryints====-1
    ========*******Encryints====0
    ========*******Encryints====116
    ========*******Encryints====0
    ========*******Encryints====101
    ========*******Encryints====0
    ========*******Encryints====115
    ========*******Encryints====0
    ========*******Encryints====116*
```

### c#  code

```
    byte[] inData = Encoding.**Unicode**.GetBytes(Str);
    for (int i = 0; i < inData.Length; i++) {
        Console.WriteLine("====EncryStrHex==inData[i]==" + inData[i]);
    }
```

#### result

```
    *========*******Encryints====116
    ========*******Encryints====0
    ========*******Encryints====101
    ========*******Encryints====0
    ========*******Encryints====115
    ========*******Encryints====0
    ========*******Encryints====116
    ========*******Encryints====0*
```

Comment: A difference between BigEndian and LittleEndian?

Comment: That code can't produce that output. Also, what the heck is `getInt`?

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be two issues here (excluding the way the examples cannot actually generate the output).

1. Your java example is encoding the data using UTF16, big endian, while the C# example is using UTF16, little endian, which explains the different positions of the zero bytes.
2. Your java example is preceding the data with a BOM (0xFFFE), byte order mark, which is intended to show which UTF encoding is used. UTF 8, 16 (BE and LE), and 32 (BE and LE), all generate different byte sequences for this character. There are arguments as to whether this is a good idea or not.